# Calculating time difference in sas (military time)

Tags: datetime, sas

I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate duration of a time variable 
Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

Comment: Are your current variables numeric (with a format of HHMM) or are they stored as character?

Comment: They are numeric

Comment: You will need date part also, or some other way to handle crossing over midnight.

Comment: Are they time values or just integers that look like HHMM values?  For example is 8:30 PM stored as 2,030 or 73,800?

Comment: Okay, I don't have a date variable-- it is coded as a weekday or weekend.

Comment: 8:30 would be coded as 2,030

Comment: Do you have the date part? to calculate the interval/diff you need datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A military time value encoded as a integer number h,hmm can be processed by converting the number to a SAS time value and then performing delta computations using certain assumptions.

```
data sleep_log;
  input name $ boots_down boots_up;
datalines;
Joe 2000 0600 slept over midnight
Joe 1000 1230 slept into lunch
Joe 1630 1700 30 winks
Joe 0100 0100 out cold!
run;

data sleep_data;
  set sleep_log;
  down = hms(
      int(boots_down / 100) /* extract hours */
    , mod(boots_down , 100) /* extract minutes */
    , 0 /* seconds not logged, use zero */
  );
  up = hms(
      int(boots_up / 100) /* extract hours */
    , mod(boots_up , 100) /* extract minutes */
    , 0 /* seconds not logged, use zero */
  );

  * SAS time values are linear and simple arithmetic can apply;

  if up <= down 
    then delta = '24:00't + up - down; /* presume roll over midnight */
    else delta = up - down;

  format down up delta time5.;
run;
```

A more robust log would also record the day, eliminating presumptions and providing a proper time dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the Hours and Minutes from your numeric military time HHMM , then create a SAS time using `HMS()` function.

1. Extract Hours: Divide your HHMM by 100 and save as integer to get hours,
2. Extract Minutes: get the Remainder (MOD) of HHMM  by 100 to get the minutes,
3. Create a new time variable using `HMS(Hour,Minute,Second)`,
4. Create a new Datetime for each using `DHMS(date,hour,minute,second)`

Full Code:

```
data have;
input sleep awake date_s date_w;
informat date_s date9. date_w date9.;
format sleep z4. awake  z4. date_s date9. date_w date9.;
datalines;
2300 0500 12feb2018 13feb2018
2000 0300 11feb2018 12feb2018
0530 1230 10feb2018 10feb2018
;
run;

data want;
set have;
new_sleep_time=hms(int(sleep/100),int(mod(sleep,100)),0);
new_awake_time=hms(int(awake/100),int(mod(awake,100)),0);
dt_awake=dhms(date_w,hour(new_awake_time),minute(new_awake_time),0);
dt_sleep=dhms(date_s,hour(new_sleep_time),minute(new_sleep_time),0);
diff=dt_awake-dt_sleep;
keep new_sleep_time new_awake_time dt_awake dt_sleep diff; 
format new_sleep_time time8. new_awake_time time8. diff time8. dt_awake datetime21. dt_sleep datetime21.;
run;
```

Output:

```
 new_sleep_time=23:00:00 new_awake_time=5:00:00 diff=6:00:00 dt_awake=13FEB2018:05:00:00 dt_sleep=12FEB2018:23:00:00 
 new_sleep_time=20:00:00 new_awake_time=3:00:00 diff=7:00:00 dt_awake=12FEB2018:03:00:00 dt_sleep=11FEB2018:20:00:00 
 new_sleep_time=5:30:00 new_awake_time=12:30:00 diff=7:00:00 dt_awake=10FEB2018:12:30:00 dt_sleep=10FEB2018:05:30:00
```